# Raspberry Pi WLAN issues with BerryBoot

Tags: wifi, raspbian-jessie, berryboot, raspbian-stretch

Yesterday I installed a Vanilla Raspbian image on BerryBoot to test out Stretch and then go back to my Jessie image.

It all went quite well until I removed it and the Pi said it could no longer connect to the Router.

After looking around the Router I removed everything related to the Pi's local IP (192.168.178.26) and the Pi got back onto the network but weirdly enough no machine can receive or connect to it, not even a simple ping as if the Pi is not connected.

It works fine over LAN but in my situation its not able to receive a constant LAN connection.

Since then I have reinstalled BerryBoot and reconfigured the Network.

This is quite a weird issue and everything I tried couldn't fix it. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my SD card from a 1GB one to a 16GB one and changed the Static IP adress now everything seems to work fine
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How could you have possibly used a 1GB card originally? Even Jessie lite is larger than that.

Comment: I found it lying around the house and fouse it as a great usage because I use BerryBoot anyways

Comment: @Jacobm001 berryboot lets you keep the OS on an external hard drive